# sorting the http get before returning to component

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently in the service i am calling `http.get` as follow

```
getList(): Observable<Customer[]> {
return this.http.get<Customer[]>("api/customers");
```

}

in component `ngOnInit` the list of customer is returned:

```
this.customerService.getList().subscribe(data => (this.customers = data));
```

It is working fine. Now i want to sorting the list before returning to the component.

any idea of how to return sorted list in the service to compnent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can sort it in the service by calling .**`sort`**,

```
this.http.get<Customer[]>("api/customers").pipe(
  map(results => results.sort(...))
);
```